# Loading data in datagrid cells into variables

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid I want to load the values in the cells into variables

I can't take in datagrid all cells value

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbkML.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to tell more about what your problem is. Assumed the DataGrid content is "normally" coming from something like a `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourObservableCollection}"/>`, then the cell values would already be there in your `DataContext` / ViewModel properties

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the `DataGrid.SelectedItems` property?, e.g. like `result=yourDdataGrid.SelectedItems.OfType<YourType>().ToList())`

Comment: I don't need a complicated operation, I just want to assign the value of the cells in datagrid to my variables. Thank you for helping me